# Updating a DataGridView when underlying MSAccess Database Changes

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I'm trying to get a DataGridView control (on tab control of Form1) to update when I write data to the underlying MS Access database from two other Forms.

I've read a vast number of replies to similar questions here on StackOverflow and all around the internet but the usual responses;
    myDataGridView.Update() 
and
     myDataGridView.Refresh() 
don't work.

Neither does
    myBindingSource.ResetBindings(false)

or changing the
     DataGridView.DataSource

by setting it null and then setting it to myBindingSource.

I've also tried using the 
    myTableAdpter.Fill(myDataSet)

approach but again absolutely nothing.

It's a WinForms application in C# using VS2017 and a simple "Refresh" button on the tab in Form1.

I'm absolutely baffled so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for any help

Regards
Matthew

p.s. Here's the current code I have for the Reset Button but it doesn't do anything.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshDisplay();
    }

    private void tabControl1_TabIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshDisplay();
    }

    private void RefreshDisplay()
    {
        sacsDataGridView.DataSource = null;
        sacsBindingSource4.ResetBindings(false);
        sacsDataGridView.DataSource = sacsBindingSource4;
        sacsDataGridView.Update();
        sacsDataGridView.Refresh();
    }
```

Regards
Matthew

Comment: Show your code. Re-binding to a data source definitely should do it.

Comment: Hi Crowcoder, Thanks for your reply; I've updated my original comment with the code for the reset button but it doesn't seem to have any effect at all? If you have any ideas that would be great. There's clearly something I'm missing here.

Comment: `DataGridView` doesn't have an `Update()` method that I can find. Is that [a Windows Forms DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.7.2) or a third party component? Anyway, the important part here is the state of `sacsBindingSource4`. Are you sure you have filled it with data?

Comment: Hi Crowcoder, Yes it's a windows forms DataGridView whih does have an Update method. It just doesn't seem to do anything. The sacsBindingSource4 is filled with data; it just happens to be the old data rather than the updated data. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi Crowcoder, if it helps I could .zip up the whole project and send it to you; I can't help but think that I'm doing something wrong on a fundamental level. Thanks, Matthew

Comment: I might look at it if you pushed it to Github but I'm a little leary of downloading things.

Comment: That's understandable; I'll give that a go. Thanks